# VSCode / failed to save

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, filesystems, vscode-extensions

Often when working on typescript files in VS code I'll get a "failed to save" error and a blank window will open up. It looks like VSC is trying to save to `/Untitled` eg the root of the file system.

This is not related to permissions errors inside my project. It's something to do with when there's an error in the .ts file it causes this spurious error to occur.

It happens a few times an hour and is driving me nuts. Has nobody else seen this? Googling just finds me basic `chown $user` type comments...

Failed to save 'Untitled-1, Untitled-1': Unable to write file '/Untitled-1' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/Untitled-1')

[image: failed to save]

Comment: still happening! must be some random extension i have installed :(